# Drupal Commerce | Hide or set an alias to the order number in the checkout path

Tags: 7, commerce

Is there any DC module or configuration that would allow me to set an alias for the order number that is shown on the checkout path.

i.e.

Instead of [example.com/checkout/10](http://example.com/checkout/10)

Something like [example.com/checkout/order](http://example.com/checkout/order) or just plain [example.com/checkout](http://example.com/checkout)

An alias module would have similar functionalities as the [me](http://drupal.org/project/me) module.

Comment: Couldn't path-auto solve this? I haven't investigated, but the functionality you are requesting looks just like the normal node aliases provided by path aliases.

Comment: @Letharion Path auto does not allow place-holders I am afraid.
For instance, it does not accept checkout/%

Comment: Of course it does, what else would be "auto" about it? "Everyone" uses it for node/%.

Comment: @Letharion Yes but the node/10 gets converted to blog/my-title-1 and node/11 to blog/my-title-2 and so on.

It wont work converting all the checkout/% to checkout/order.

It does not have the option, as node, taxonomy and user do, for setting checkout/[customer-name] or something.

Comment: You can never have an alias on checkout/% to checkout/order, as the system couldn't separate the different % from each other then.
There's a [path-auto fork](http://drupal.org/sandbox/damz/1332096) that seemingly makes path-auto entity agnostic, meaning you could use it on any entity, including orders. The sandbox also has a link the relevant feature request.

Comment: Ah, now I understand more, I missed the "me" module and it's description before. That's very different from an alias though, which is what confused me. Can a user only have one order in your system? Otherwise I don't see how this makes sense?

Comment: To be honest I didn't think it through when it comes to an unique user having more than one order. What bothered me was the fact that people can see how many orders I got in the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that my goal is not feasible because the system could not distinguish orders of an unique user who has more than one order in the system.

I will encrypt the order number bit by implementing [hook_url_outbound_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7) and [hook_url_inbound_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7).

Answer (score 1):

I to went that road, did not want customers to see an on each order incrementing ID in URL's. In `hook_url_outbound_alter()` *any* path can be encrypted by altering the regular expression.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_url_inbound_alter().
 */
function mymodule_url_inbound_alter(&$path, $original_path, $path_language) {
  // Decrypt paths that are encrypted by our hook_url_outbound_alter() to hide possible id's in paths.
  if (preg_match('#^ENC:(.+)#', $path, $m)) {
    $path = _mymodule_mcrypt('decrypt', $m[1]);
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_url_outbound_alter().
 */
function mymodule_url_outbound_alter(&$path, &$options, $original_path) {
  // To hide id's in paths, we encrypt them.
  if (preg_match('#^checkout/.*#', $path, $m)) {
    $path = 'ENC:' . _mymodule_mcrypt('encrypt', $path);
  }
}

/**
 * Helper function to encrypt and decrypt strings, ie. paths to hide containing id's.
 * NB: We replace forward slashes for exclamation marks, otherwise trailing 
 *     slashes in the URL will be ignored by Drupal.
 */
function _mymodule_mcrypt($action, $string, $key = null) {
  if (!$key) {
    $key = $GLOBALS['drupal_hash_salt'];
  }

  $mcrypt_method = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128;
  $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size($mcrypt_method, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);

  // Make key exactly as long as long as $iv_size.
  $key = substr(str_repeat($key, CEIL($iv_size / strlen($key))), 0, $iv_size);

  if ($action == 'encrypt') {
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $encrypted_string = base64_encode($iv . mcrypt_encrypt($mcrypt_method, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
    return preg_replace('#/#', '!', $encrypted_string);
  }
  elseif ($action == 'decrypt') {
    $decrypted_string = base64_decode(preg_replace('#!#', '/', $string));
    $iv = substr($decrypted_string, 0, $iv_size);
    $decrypted_string = substr($decrypted_string, $iv_size);

    return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt($mcrypt_method, $key, $decrypted_string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
  }

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully there is a new Drupal module for that named [Commerce_Checkout_Paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_paths).

[image: Commerce Checkout Paths admin page]

Comment: Cool. I will definitely try it out. Cheers.